# Is it possible to apply an attribute to a class and assembly at the same time?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, .net-assembly

I need to find all types with a [MyAttribute] in a given assembly as fast as possible. Obviously the fallback is to just use GetTypes and check IsDefined on each of them, but I'm looking at ways to speed it up because this code will be run for multiple assemblies every time they are loaded (in Unity this means every time the user modifies a script).

I've come up with two potential solutions:

1. Make an assembly attribute containing a method which uses GetTypes and IsDefined to build a string declaring that attribute like: `[assembly: AssemblyContains(new Type[] { typeof(TypeA), typeof(TypeB), ...`, and then log that string so it can be copied into one of the source files of the assembly.
2. Make an assembly attribute that needs to be declared alongside every instance of MyAttribute like: `[assembly: AssemblyContains(typeof(MyClass))] [MyAttribute] public class MyClass { ... }`.

I expect #1 would be a tiny bit more efficient, but it would be more effort to use and you could easily forget to update it when adding new classes, so I'm leaning towards #2.

So my question: is #2 a good solution and/or can you suggest a better approach?

Comment: I feel like `GetTypes` would be plenty fast enough if this is the kind of operation you only need to do once.

Comment: Agree with Abion. It feels like you are either trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist or solve it in the wrong way.

Comment: I'm not trying to solve a problem as such. I'm just trying to create the best possible product, which means minimising the impact it has on the user's load time.

Comment: You really should measure if what you trying to optimize has any impact at all - setting up/tearing down app domains necessary for such code is not exactly cheapest operation...

Comment: When "minimizing the load time" means the difference between 50ms and 35 ms, it's not worth the optimization effort.